# How to allow a user to view data that is added only by him Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools

I have a Django application, where the user with restricted access registers a new post in Django admin.

This user can only see in the table to register, update and delete the posts inserted by him, and can not view the posts entered by another user, all within Admin Django, unless it has super user status.

I've tried to create "def queryset" in my "NoticiaAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin)" class, and unfortunately I do not know what I'm doing wrong, I can not solve this problem.

Here is my queryset function...

```
def queryset(self, request): 
    if request.user.is_superuser: 
        qs = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set() 
    else: 
        qs = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set().filter(user=request.user) 
    ordering = self.ordering or () 
    if ordering: 
        qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)     
    return qs
```

I hope that I have clarified my doubts about the problem and I will be very grateful to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to call `super()` on the method in the `ModelAdmin`class.

Maybe try something like this,

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Many thanks my friend, fantastic, worked exactly as I was trying. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please do me a favour and tag the answer as selected, then?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to see where I do this because it's my first time here in "StackOverflow"

Comment: This could be helpful .. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: I think I got it.